# Python tkinter GUI for Serial Communication

Tags: tkinter, serial-communication

I am totally new to python language and now is learning to use python for creating GUI to interface with MCU for my own project. My concept is to create multiple windows -> For front end user and back end developer. I managed to create UI for both windows and establish serial communication with MCU. However, I couldn't synchronize the data response for both windows. For my scenario, I want to create a button for data push, and from the UI it will show response, for both windows at the same time. How do I do that, hope someone can enlighten me. Thank you in advance

I tried using thread, but it seems not suitable for synchronizing data response from both windows. Or maybe I'm not using it correctly. I am getting response update from front end window sometimes, and backend window sometimes.

```
import serial
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from serial.tools import list_ports
import time
import threading

sent_data_logs = []  # List to store the data sent logs
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 19200, timeout=0.1)
data = ser.readline().decode().strip()

#############################################################
#Serial

class Config_window:
    def __init__(self, config_window, on_configure=True):
        self.root = config_window
        self.root.title("Serial Configuration")
        self.on_configure = on_configure
        self.default_baudrate = tk.StringVar(value="19200")
        self.default_parity = tk.StringVar(value="None")
        self.default_stopbits = tk.StringVar(value="1")

        self.create_widgets()
        self.btn_confirm = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Confirm", command=self.configure_serial)
        self.btn_confirm.pack()
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label_baudrate = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Baud Rate:")
        self.label_baudrate.pack()
        self.combo_baudrate = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=["9600","19200", "115200", "57600"])
        self.combo_baudrate.pack()
        self.combo_baudrate.set(self.default_baudrate.get())

        self.label_port = ttk.Label(self.root, text="COM Port:")
        self.label_port.pack()
        self.combo_port = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=self.get_available_ports())
        self.combo_port.pack()

        self.label_parity = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Parity:")
        self.label_parity.pack()
        self.combo_parity = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=["None", "Even", "Odd", "Mark", "Space"])
        self.combo_parity.pack()
        self.combo_parity.set(self.default_parity.get())

        self.label_stopbits = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Stop Bits:")
        self.label_stopbits.pack()
        self.combo_stopbits = ttk.Combobox(self.root, values=["1", "1.5", "2"])
        self.combo_stopbits.pack()
        self.combo_stopbits.set(self.default_stopbits.get())

        self.btn_set_default = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Set Default", command=self.set_default)
        self.btn_set_default.pack()


    def get_available_ports(self):
        return [port.device for port in list_ports.comports()]

    def set_default(self):
        self.default_baudrate.set("19200")
        self.default_parity.set("None")
        self.default_stopbits.set("1")
        self.combo_baudrate.set(self.default_baudrate.get())
        self.combo_parity.set(self.default_parity.get())
        self.combo_stopbits.set(self.default_stopbits.get())

    def configure_serial(self):
        baudrate = int(self.combo_baudrate.get())
        port = self.combo_port.get()
        parity_mapping = {
            "None": serial.PARITY_NONE,
            "Even": serial.PARITY_EVEN,
            "Odd": serial.PARITY_ODD,
            "Mark": serial.PARITY_MARK,
            "Space": serial.PARITY_SPACE
        }
        parity = parity_mapping[self.combo_parity.get()]
    
        stopbits_mapping = {
            "1": serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            "1.5": serial.STOPBITS_ONE_POINT_FIVE,
            "2": serial.STOPBITS_TWO
        }
        stopbits = stopbits_mapping[self.combo_stopbits.get()]
    
        self.confirmed_serial_settings = {
            "baudrate": baudrate,
            "port": port,
            "parity": parity,
            "stopbits": stopbits
        }   
        if self.on_configure:
            self.on_configure(self.confirmed_serial_settings)

    def configure_serial_port(self, baudrate, port, parity, stopbits):
        ser = serial.Serial()
        ser.baudrate = baudrate
        ser.port = port
        ser.parity = parity
        ser.stopbits = stopbits

        try:
            ser.open()
            return ser
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print("Error:", e)
            return None
######################################################################

def Set_IR_Library():
    data_to_send = "3:irdev-B079010FE20FE20FE20F000100103600240ED80100000000100010001000320100000200051E0900001003C900860041090800100536008600410910001005360086004100240011DA2700C50000D711DA27004200005411DA270000392000A0000006600000C18000C5151E051501D4D80F051502D4D800081E003840004048D7081E013840104048E70B1003C8CC0A03C8CC0303C8CC0503C8CC071616045F004806043F003606083F04123704153F091E37040C0803CCD00F03CCD00000D4070104000216080605040111232302030217020A1A03B0B40303B0B40403B0B40006B0B406B8C03206B0B402B8C0C0170A1E05010300051E010100147F04090A081205036108064807801603F016010A078089C008890B06200100021B1C4149C13C007800B400F0002C016801A401E0011C0258029402D002010505036109063607801603F016010D078089C009890B061A0100021C1D414991C6038607460B060FC6128616461A061EC6210105060001A11E0001060001B1210084\r\n"
    encoded_data = data_to_send.encode()
# Convert the data string to bytes
    ser.write(encoded_data)

def Set_IR_Signal():
    Json_data = {
    "power": "on",
    "fan": "high",
    "mode": "heat",
    "hlouver": "off",
    "vlouver": "off",
    "temperature": "22.0",
    "fid": "power"
}
    Json_string = f'3:runStatus-{Json_data}'
    Json_string += '\r\n'
    encoded_data = Json_string.encode()
# Convert the data string to bytes
    ser.write(encoded_data)

##backend
def open_new_window():
        password = password_entry.get()
        if password == "123":  # Replace "your_password_here" with the actual password
            new_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
            new_window.title("New Window")
            btn_serial_config = tk.Button(new_window, text="Open Serial Configuration", command=open_serial_configuration)
            btn_serial_config.pack()
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Access Denied", "Incorrect password!")

        def send_data():
            data = entry_data.get()
            if data:
                data = convert_data(data)

                if cb_cr_lf.get():
                    data += b'\r\n'
                
                ser.write(data)

        def convert_data(data):
            data_type = None
            if cb_hex.get():
                data_type = 'hex'
            elif cb_oct.get():
                data_type = 'oct'
            elif cb_bin.get():
                data_type = 'bin'
            elif cb_dec.get():
                data_type = 'dec'
        
            if data_type:
                try:
                    if data_type == 'hex':
                        data = bytes.fromhex(data)
                    elif data_type == 'oct':
                        data = int(data, 8).to_bytes((len(data) + 2) // 3, byteorder='big')
                    elif data_type == 'bin':
                        data = int(data, 2).to_bytes((len(data) + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')
                    elif data_type == 'dec':
                        data = int(data).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input for the selected data type.")
                    return b''
            else:
                try:
                    data = data.encode()
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    print("Invalid input for ASCII data.")
                    return b''
            sent_data_logs.append(data)  # Log the data
            text_send.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            for sent_data in sent_data_logs:
                text_send.insert(tk.END, f">> {sent_data.hex()}\n")
            return data

# Data Input
        label_data = ttk.Label(new_window, text="Enter Data:")
        label_data.pack()
        entry_data = ttk.Entry(new_window)
        entry_data.pack()

# Data Type Checkboxes
        cb_hex = tk.BooleanVar()
        cb_oct = tk.BooleanVar()
        cb_bin = tk.BooleanVar()
        cb_dec = tk.BooleanVar()

        chk_hex = ttk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="Hex", variable=cb_hex)
        chk_hex.pack()
        chk_oct = ttk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="Oct", variable=cb_oct)
        chk_oct.pack()
        chk_bin = ttk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="Bin", variable=cb_bin)
        chk_bin.pack()
        chk_dec = ttk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="Dec", variable=cb_dec)
        chk_dec.pack()

# Add Carriage Return and Line Feed
        cb_cr_lf = tk.BooleanVar()
        chk_cr_lf = ttk.Checkbutton(new_window, text="Add CR/LF", variable=cb_cr_lf)
        chk_cr_lf.pack()

        btn_send_IR_signal = ttk.Button(new_window, text="Set IR Library", command = Set_IR_Library)
        btn_send_IR_signal.pack()

        btn_send_IR_signal = ttk.Button(new_window, text="Send IR Signal", command = Set_IR_Signal)
        btn_send_IR_signal.pack()
        # Send Data Button
        btn_send = ttk.Button(new_window, text="Send Data", command=send_data)
        btn_send.pack()

        # Data Monitor
        frame_monitor = ttk.LabelFrame(new_window, text="Data Monitor")
        frame_monitor.pack()

    # Data Sending Monitor
        label_send_monitor = ttk.Label(frame_monitor, text="Data Sending:")
        label_send_monitor.pack()
        text_send = tk.Text(frame_monitor, width=50, height=10)
        text_send.pack()

        # Data Receiving Monitor
        label_receive_monitor = ttk.Label(frame_monitor, text="Data Receiving:")
        label_receive_monitor.pack()
        text_receive = tk.Text(frame_monitor, width=50, height=10)
        text_receive.pack()

#backend
        def update_receive_monitor():
            data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            time.sleep(1)
            if data:
                text_receive.insert(tk.END, f">> {data}\n")
                text_receive.see(tk.END)

            receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_receive_monitor)
            receive_thread.daemon = True
            receive_thread.start()
            
        def clear_log():
            text_send.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            text_receive.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            sent_data_logs.clear()
        btn_clear_log = ttk.Button(new_window, text="Clear Log", command=clear_log)
        btn_clear_log.pack()

        update_receive_monitor()
# Start monitoring data receiving

def open_serial_configuration():
    config_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    config_window.title("Serial Configuration")
    Config_window(config_window)

#front end
def write_data_to_serial():
    # Write hexadecimal byte (0x1B)
        ser.write(b'\x1B\x1B\x1B\x1B\x1B')
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # Write "3:PRD?" command with carriage return and line feed
        ser.write("3:PRD?\r\n".encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # Write "3:FWV" command with carriage return and line feed
        ser.write("3:FWV\r\n".encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)

def read_data_from_serial():
        while True:
            data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            time.sleep(1.5) #1.5 sec delay to display result on front end monitor
            if data:
                result = check_test_result(data)
                text_receive.insert(tk.END, f">> {data}\n")  # Append data to a new line
                text_receive.insert(tk.END, f"Result: {result}\n")  # Display the test result
                text_receive.see(tk.END)

def check_test_result(data):
    if ".abc" in data:
        return "Test Successful"
    else:
        return "Test Failed"


def on_close():
    write_data_to_serial()
    root.destroy()

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_data_from_serial)
receive_thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize the thread to allow exiting the program


receive_thread.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.title("Main Window")
    ttk.Label(root, text="Front End User Window").pack()
    tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=write_data_to_serial).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
    tk.Button(root, text="Stop").pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)
    frame_monitor = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Data Monitor")
    frame_monitor.pack()
    label_receive_monitor = ttk.Label(root, text="Data Receiving:")
    label_receive_monitor.pack()
    text_receive = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=10)
    text_receive.pack()

    tk.Button(root, text="Open New Window", command=open_new_window).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    password_entry = tk.Entry(root, show="*")  # Entry widget to hide the password characters
    password_entry.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter password to access new window:")
    password_label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    root.mainloop()
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjZxm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN29i.png)